# do the mythbuntu repo's serve mythtv 29.1?

Tags: mythbuntu

I am currently using ubuntu 16.04 with mythtv .29.0+Fixes from the mythbuntu repo's.  I see that mythtv 29.1 is out, will i be getting that?  Do i need to change my source?  If so, to what?

thanks in advance

Comment: Which Mythbuntu repos?

Comment: hi, not sure what you are asking, these are the .29+fixes repo for mythtv

Comment: Where did you get these repos from? What sources have you added for these repos?